# Samsung - Change password / log-in method with NFC

Tags: lock-screens, samsung, nfc

I had some NFC tags with my Xperia Sola. It could change settings if I touched the tags with the phone, and it was pretty useful.
Can one use this "technology" with modern Samsung phones?

Both removing/setting the password (with two tags), or just unlocking the screen (one tag) would be awesome.
The first would be better, of course. As I could just get home, touch the tag, and then I can use my phone real easy. When I head out or just leave the house, I can touch the password tag and get it locked like I use it on the street.
Changing the password/lock settings by hand each time is a real hassle.